# script em que determinada hora e dia da semana redireciona o usuário para uma página em específico

Tags: javascript, data, script

Estou tentando criar um script para que uma página redirecione o usuário para uma outra dependendo do dia da semana e do horário. Encontrei algo, mas não deu certo:

`
function CheckTime() {

var SaticDate     = new Date();
var mdia          = SaticDate.getDate();
var mdiasemana    = SaticDate.getDay();
var mhora         = SaticDate.getHours()
var mminutos      = SaticDate.getMinutes();

else if(mdiasemana == 0) {
window.open("https://google.com");
}

else if(mdiasemana == 4 && mhora >= 14 && mminutos >= 00 && mhora <= 15 && mminutos <= 05) {
window.open("https://apple.com/br");
}
else if(mdiasemana == 4 && mhora >= 15 && mminutos >= 06 && mhora <= 16 && mminutos <= 45) {
window.open("https://microsoft.com");
}

else {
window.setTimeout("CheckTime();", (60 * 1000));
}
}

CheckTime();
`

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.setInterval(function(){ // Setando intervalo de tempo
    var date = new Date(); // Criando o Objeto Date();
    if(date.getHours() === 20 && date.getMinutes() === 35){ // Verificando a hora
        // Executando o codigo
        window.open("www.google.com");
    }
}, 60000); // Verificando o codigo a cada 60000 Milisegundos (1min)
```

Haverá um atraso para executar o script, pois o mesmo é verificado de minuto em minuto. É feito isso para que o mesmo site nao seja aberto 2 vezes no mesmo minuto

Alguns navegadores poderão bloquear a abertura da nova Janela, por causa do CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)